# Where can I find ffmpeg codecs for Windows Chromium (h.264, AAC, mp3..)?

Tags: ffmpeg, chromium

In previous version you could copy files from google Chrome's folders and paste them into the Chromium files, but that doesn't work anymore. Apparently all the files have been replaced by  1 file ffmpegsumo.dll, copying that from Chrome changes nothing.

I downloaded codecs for Chromium on linux, but I find it weird that there's no way to get them for Windows.

Why don't they just add h.264 to chromium now that cisco made it royalty free?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google has little incentive to support H.264 when they have their own, competing format [WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) that they are trying to push. (Haven’t you ever wondered why such a relatively unknown format is one of the formats the YouTube, a Google subsidiary, supports natively?)

Unfortunately, as you have learned, they re-structured Chromium so that you cannot easily drop in H.264 support as you could before. What you can try instead, is to use the [Microsoft plugin](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/wmp-extension-for-chrome) that lets Chromium play H.264 through Windows Media Player. Because it is a plugin, it should still work—unless Google specifically blocked it.

Comment: (It isn’t really a surprise that [Microsoft did that move](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/microsoft-adds-h-264-support-to-google-chrome/2937) since it kills two birds with one stone: it undermine’s a competitor, and it strengthens their own brand.)

Comment: The plugin doesn't even work on Chromium anymore either.

Comment: That link is dead. Is there an updated Windows workaround?